# Trying to instantiate JavaScript class in a html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I'm trying to instantiate a JavaScript class in another HTML file.

Here is the JavaScript class:

```
class Puzzle {
  constructor(fenStart, pgnEnd) {
    this.fenStart = fenStart;
    this.pgnEnd = pgnEnd;
  }
}

module.exports = Puzzle;
```

And here is the HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="class.js"></script>
        <p id="demo"></p>

        <script>
            var demoEL = $('#demo');

            const x = new Puzzle("fenStart", "pgnEnd");

            demoEL.html(x.fenStart);
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

However when ever I open the HTML file in chrome nothing appears on the page. And in the developer console I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined, at class.js:8" How can I properly instantiate the puzzle class in this HTML file?

**PS:** I read that JQuery might be needed for this so I downloaded "jquery-3.2.1.min.js" and included it in the same folder as the JavaScript class and the HTML file.

Comment: Are you getting any error in the console?? Check in the developers tool once. require might not be supported.

Comment: In the developer tools I am getting the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined, at class.js:8"

Comment: You will not need to export the Puzzle module as it is already defined in the global namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you don't need module.exports 
You can directly create the object and update the DOM. If at all you want to use modules in the browser you can use a module bundler like webpack

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to say `module.exports = Puzzle;`
this is what I did and it works fine.

> JS

```
class Puzzle {
 constructor(fenStart, pgnEnd) {
this.fenStart = fenStart;
this.pgnEnd = pgnEnd;
 }}
```

> HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <body>
     <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="class.js"></script>
     <p id="demo"></p>

     <script>
        var demoEL = $('#demo');

        const x = new Puzzle("fenStart", "pgnEnd");

        console.log(x.fenStart);
        console.log(x.pgnEnd);
    </script> 
    </body>
   </html>
```

---

since we are on the subject I highly recommend of using pseudoclassical pattern 
this pattern will make your life much easier if you are planning to add a function to your class

just to clarify this is an example of your class :

> pseudoclassical patern - HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <body>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="class.js"></script>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        var demoEL = $('#demo');

        const x = new Puzzle("fenStart", "pgnEnd");

        console.log(x.fenStart);
        console.log(x.pgnEnd);
        var bla = x.bla();
        console.log(bla);
    </script> 
</body>
```

> pseudoclassical pattern - JS :

```
var Puzzle = function(fenStart,pgnEnd){
this.fenStart = fenStart;
this.pgnEnd = pgnEnd;
}


Puzzle.prototype.bla = function(){ // some other function
return "bla";
}
```

that's all, have a nice coding.